# Set value or NULL if not found

Tags: mysql

I have this query that sets the ID of a users active trip if it's within the current date. This works for all the users that have an actual trip going on. The problem is, some people don't have a trip so I want them to instead have `NULL`.

```
UPDATE vc_user u
LEFT JOIN vc_trip t ON t.user_id=u.id
SET u.c_current_trip=t.id
WHERE t.date_start <= :date AND t.date_end >= :date
```

I understand that the query will only run if the dates are within range, but I can't wrap my head around how to actually write the query to also set the `NULL` for users who don't have a trip going on.

Comment: Could you run two queries? The first sets them all to null. The second updates only those that have a trip (so, an inner join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use date condition on join clause like below:
when u use where clause in left/right join then it acts like inner join, so to get all rows from left or right table you need to specify other clauses on join

```
UPDATE vc_user u
LEFT JOIN vc_trip t ON t.user_id=u.id and t.date_start <= :date AND t.date_end >= :date
SET u.c_current_trip=t.id
```

Comment: Wow, this is perfect! Thank you so much!